# Access Telephone number using android app

Tags: android

Through my android app I want to retrieve  the telephone number of the phone which that app runs. For that I use below method.

```
public void findTeleNumber(){
        TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE); 
        teleNumber = tm.getLine1Number();

        Toast.makeText(this, teleNumber , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
```

But this method returns a null value for telephone number. Is there an alternative way for find the telephone number ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23675998/3492139

Answer (score 0):

Use below code :

```
TelephonyManager tMgr = (TelephonyManager)mAppContext.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
String mPhoneNumber = tMgr.getLine1Number();
```

In AndroidManifest.xml, give the following permission:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```

But remember, this code does not always work, since Cell phone number is dependent on the SIM Card and the Network operator / Cell phone carrier.

Also, try checking in ***Phone--> Settings --> About --> Phone Identity***, If you are able to view the Number there, the probability of getting the phone number from above code is higher. If you are not able to view the phone number in the settings, then you won't be able to get via this code!

**Suggested Workaround:**

1. Get the user's phone number as manual input from the user.
2. Send a code to the user's mobile number via SMS.
3. Ask user to enter the code to confirm the phone number.
4. Save the number in sharedpreference.

Do the above 4 steps as one time activity during the app's first launch. Later on, whenever phone number is required, use the value available in shared preference.